# How to calculate this integral.

Tags: calculus

when $t\in(0,1)$:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\tan x)^{1-2t}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u^{-t}(1-u)^{t-1}\,du$$
I don't know how to get this equation.

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal? Do you know about Gamma functions?

Comment: @kobe yes, I only want to know how to get this equation by substitution. I have already know Gamma functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use trigonometric substitutions. Let $y = \sin x$ so $dy = \cos x dx$ and $u = y^2$ so $du = 2y dy$. We then have
\begin{align}
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} (\tan x)^{1 - 2t} dx &= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \tan x (\tan^2 x)^{-t} dx\\
&= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x} (\frac{\sin^2 x}{1 -\sin^2 x })^{-t}  \cos xdx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{y}{1 - y^2}(\frac{y^2}{1 - y^2})^{-t} dy\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1  (y^2)^{-t}(1 - y^2)^{t - 1} 2y dy\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u^{-t} (1 - u)^{t - 1} du
\end{align}
as required.